# How do I “Web Scrape” a complex html document in C#?

Tags: c#, html, json, web-scraping, visual-studio-2015

## I'm currently working on a project in Visual Studio 2015 (C#).

My project is essentially a bit complex, even more for me because I have very little programming experience and knowledge, but every guy/gal had that time when they decided to enter the world of programming and give it their best.  With this mentality I decided to start gaining some experience and knowledge by creating a program that would be useful for others and myself, and after deciding which project I was going to face, I did some research and decided to face it with (C#). I do have decent graphic design skills, so I know that the design is not going to give me much trouble. The coding though, I’m going to have to learn, but fortunately I’m a relatively fast learner and have decent patience.

As you read the code I think you will have an idea about what the project‘s about. SPOILER ALERT! It’s a tool for the Xbox One. It’s been about a week since I started this project, and it’s moving at a good pace. I’ve had plenty of questions of course, but I’ve been able to answer them with a bit of research. Unfortunately I haven’t been able to find the answer to my latest question.

---

## How do I “Web Scrape” a complex html document, which I have saved as a “.txt” after getting the source code of the desired website?

**(By the way, sorry if I don’t use the correct terms to identify or describe things. I’m pretty new to coding and lack the knowledge of some terms.)**

I’ve seen a lot of methods which targets a specific “nodes” like; `<strong></strong>`, `<A HREF></A>`, and other isolated “nodes”. But, the website which I’m scraping is a bit more complex, and has “div classes” inside of other statements (“nodes”), which I need to get the data out of.

Currently I was testing out the “scraping” by gathering the collected data in “listboxes”. As shown in the code bellow:

**(Some code has been changed for safety purposes like; names, addresses, account info, ect.)**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TheProjectName
{
    public partial class Form2OrgTest : Form
    {
        public Form2OrgTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> gamertags = new List<string>();
            List<string> gamerpic = new List<string>();
            List<string> activeStatusOnOffline = new List<string>();

            string xbFrSourceCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:...\TheProjectName\bin\Debug\xbFrSourceCode.txt");
            MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(xbFrSourceCode, @"", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            foreach (Match m in m1)
            {
                string gamertag = m.Groups[1].Value;
                gamertags.Add(gamertag);
            }
            listBoxGamerTags.DataSource = gamertags;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm looking to gather that data and group them so that the program can create multiple objects based on that data, and if you know a way to do this… feel free to share.

The fallowing code is the part of the source code I gathered that I would like to gather the data from.

```
    <div class="friendsPageContent" role="main">
    <div id="pendingRequestsContent" class="pendingRequestsContent">
            <div class="contentTitle">
                <div class="title">
                    Pending Requests on Xbox 360 (1)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="personListWrapper">
                <div class="inlinePromptMessageWrapper">
    <div class="iconWrapper">
        <img class="successIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/checkmark_icon.png" />
        <img class="errorIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/error_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="promptMessage"></div>
</div>

<div class="gamerList">
    <ul>

                    <li data-gamertag="PGC HALO 4"
                data-appdisplayname="PGC HALO 4"
                data-isfavorite="False"
                data-isonline="False"
                data-isfriend="False"
                data-xbox360relationship="FriendRequester"
                data-property=""
                class="left" tabindex="2">
                <a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=PGC%20HALO%204" class="gamerpicWrapper">
                    <img alt="PGC HALO 4" aria-label="PGC HALO 4" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=mHGRD8KXEf2sp2LC58XhBQKNl2IWRp.J.q8mSURKUUcuU3gBRe_BRDdzRW_paApMdVcvsw86El1cEiX5.qTNgINJAP5HhuI8ujjddktTirA-&amp;format=png&amp;h=64&amp;w=64" title="PGC HALO 4"></img>
                    <div class="favoriteIconWrapper">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="statusIcon">
                </div>
                <div class="friendInfo">
                    <div class="gamertagWrapper">
                        <div class="gamertag"><a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=PGC%20HALO%204" title="PGC HALO 4">PGC HALO 4</a></div>
<img alt="Send" aria_label="Send" class="messageIcon disableSendMsg" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_sendmessage.png" title="Send" />
                        <div class="addFriendsIconWrapper addFriendIcon">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">


                        <div class="nameInfo">
                            <div class="realName"></div>
                            <div class="primaryInfo">Offline</div>
                            <div class="secondaryInfo"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <ul class="pendingRequestAction">
                                <li data-action="accept">Accept</li>
                                <li data-action="decline">Decline</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img alt="Selected" aria_label="Selected" class="selectedBoxIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/selected_box.png" title="Selected" />
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>

            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

    <div id="favoritesContent" class="favoritesContent">
            <div class="contentTitle">
                <div class="title">
                    Favorites (6)
                </div>
                <div class="editButtonWrapper ">
                    <div class="edit">
                        <span>Edit</span>
                        <ul class="subMenuButtons">
                            <li data-action="removeFavorites">Remove Favorites</li>
                            <li data-action="removeFriends">Remove Friends</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="personListWrapper">
                <div class="inlinePromptMessageWrapper">
    <div class="iconWrapper">
        <img class="successIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/checkmark_icon.png" />
        <img class="errorIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/error_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="promptMessage"></div>
</div>

<div class="gamerList">
    <ul>


            <li data-gamertag="EMADISORT"
                data-appdisplayname="EMADISORT"
                data-isfavorite="True"
                data-isonline="False"
                data-isfriend="True"
                data-xbox360relationship="None"
                data-property=""
                class="" tabindex="2">
                <a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=EMADISORT" class="gamerpicWrapper">
                    <img alt="EMADISORT" aria-label="EMADISORT" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=z951ykn43p4FqWbbFvR2Ec.8vbDhj8G2Xe7JngaTToBrrCmIEEXHC9UNrdJ6P7KIm2RQQtfSX9jMSatOYowOzFGrmXRC0uhY67.hdTPTY6qmHE5qXdhV4CSdn79W3yys&amp;format=png&amp;h=100&amp;w=100" title="EMADISORT"></img>
                    <div class="favoriteIconWrapper">
<img class="favorite" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_favorites_mark.png" />                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="statusIcon">
                </div>
                <div class="friendInfo">
                    <div class="gamertagWrapper">
                        <div class="gamertag"><a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=EMADISORT" title="EMADISORT">EMADISORT</a></div>
<img alt="Send" aria_label="Send" class="messageIcon enableSendMsg" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_sendmessage.png" title="Send" />
                        <div class="addFriendsIconWrapper addFriendIcon">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">


                        <div class="nameInfo">
                            <div class="realName">Francisco Maldonado</div>
                            <div class="primaryInfo">Last seen: Blu-ray Player (Xbox One)</div>
                            <div class="secondaryInfo">17 hours ago</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img alt="Selected" aria_label="Selected" class="selectedBoxIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/selected_box.png" title="Selected" />
            </li>
            <li data-gamertag="RETROJohn28"
                data-appdisplayname="RETROJohn28"
                data-isfavorite="True"
                data-isonline="False"
                data-isfriend="True"
                data-xbox360relationship="None"
                data-property=""
                class="" tabindex="2">
                <a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=RETROJohn28" class="gamerpicWrapper">
                    <img alt="RETROJohn28" aria-label="RETROJohn28" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=7OTVnZUMVj4OV2zUUGecWvn3U00nQQLfK7_kwpANoghUbFr9yJJ5TKwf50f56ObUKQhspff09b0Q5DkZtZERZGTlko0WKLI_oriNztrv10bi4cScl8nJu22JzQ3uQ9i7RYykjz75wQfeWzLhiS1Dh92GP0cM9HLM1L8ruyAAt_Q-&amp;format=png&amp;h=100&amp;w=100" title="RETROJohn28"></img>
                    <div class="favoriteIconWrapper">
<img class="favorite" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_favorites_mark.png" />                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="statusIcon">
                </div>
                <div class="friendInfo">
                    <div class="gamertagWrapper">
                        <div class="gamertag"><a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=RETROJohn28" title="RETROJohn28">RETROJohn28</a></div>
<img alt="Send" aria_label="Send" class="messageIcon enableSendMsg" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_sendmessage.png" title="Send" />
                        <div class="addFriendsIconWrapper addFriendIcon">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">


                        <div class="nameInfo">
                            <div class="realName"></div>
                            <div class="primaryInfo">Last seen: Home (Xbox One)</div>
                            <div class="secondaryInfo">18 hours ago</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img alt="Selected" aria_label="Selected" class="selectedBoxIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/selected_box.png" title="Selected" />
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
                <ul class="actionButtons">
                    <li class="action"></li>
                    <li class="cancel"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="friendsContent" class="friendsContent" role="list">
        <div class="contentTitle">
            <div class="title">
                All Friends (126)
            </div>
            <div class="editButtonWrapper ">
                <div class="edit">
                    <span>Edit</span>
                    <ul class="subMenuButtons">
                            <li data-action="addFavorites">Add Favorites</li>
                        <li data-action="removeFriends">Remove Friends</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="personListWrapper">
            <div class="inlinePromptMessageWrapper">
    <div class="iconWrapper">
        <img class="successIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/checkmark_icon.png" />
        <img class="errorIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/error_icon.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="promptMessage"></div>
</div>
            <ul class="actionButtons beforeList">
                <li class="action"></li>
                <li class="cancel"></li>
            </ul>

<div class="gamerList">
    <ul>


            <li data-gamertag="DR Jandrox"
                data-appdisplayname="DR Jandrox"
                data-isfavorite="False"
                data-isonline="True"
                data-isfriend="True"
                data-xbox360relationship="None"
                data-property=""
                class="" tabindex="2">
                <a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=DR%20Jandrox" class="gamerpicWrapper">
                    <img alt="DR Jandrox" aria-label="DR Jandrox" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=z951ykn43p4FqWbbFvR2Ec.8vbDhj8G2Xe7JngaTToBrrCmIEEXHC9UNrdJ6P7KIFXxmxGDtE9Vkd62rOpb7JehA8dSapBHnH1CYJpGcvrqx3u3aQ5NMCKRX1WaLAVwB&amp;format=png&amp;h=100&amp;w=100" title="DR Jandrox"></img>
                    <div class="favoriteIconWrapper">
<img class="unFavorite" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_favorites_mark.png" />                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="statusIcon">
<img alt="Online" aria_label="Online" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_greendot.png" title="Online" />                </div>
                <div class="friendInfo">
                    <div class="gamertagWrapper">
                        <div class="gamertag"><a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=DR%20Jandrox" title="DR Jandrox">DR Jandrox</a></div>
<img alt="Send" aria_label="Send" class="messageIcon enableSendMsg" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_sendmessage.png" title="Send" />
                        <div class="addFriendsIconWrapper addFriendIcon">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">


                        <div class="nameInfo">
                            <div class="realName">Sam .</div>
                            <div class="primaryInfo">Halo 5: Guardians - Arena: Slayer (Xbox One)</div>
                            <div class="secondaryInfo"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img alt="Selected" aria_label="Selected" class="selectedBoxIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/selected_box.png" title="Selected" />
            </li>
            <li data-gamertag="YeYo24"
                data-appdisplayname="YeYo24"
                data-isfavorite="False"
                data-isonline="True"
                data-isfriend="True"
                data-xbox360relationship="None"
                data-property=""
                class="left" tabindex="2">
                <a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=YeYo24" class="gamerpicWrapper">
                    <img alt="YeYo24" aria-label="YeYo24" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=z951ykn43p4FqWbbFvR2Ec.8vbDhj8G2Xe7JngaTToBrrCmIEEXHC9UNrdJ6P7KIFXxmxGDtE9Vkd62rOpb7JWR2luWb..XqNjhsh9IW__NTYoeaUE1vI8ypnzWrmrV_&amp;format=png&amp;h=100&amp;w=100" title="YeYo24"></img>
                    <div class="favoriteIconWrapper">
<img class="unFavorite" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_favorites_mark.png" />                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="statusIcon">
<img alt="Online" aria_label="Online" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_greendot.png" title="Online" />                </div>
                <div class="friendInfo">
                    <div class="gamertagWrapper">
                        <div class="gamertag"><a href="/en-US/Profile?GamerTag=YeYo24" title="YeYo24">YeYo24</a></div>
<img alt="Send" aria_label="Send" class="messageIcon enableSendMsg" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/icon_sendmessage.png" title="Send" />
                        <div class="addFriendsIconWrapper addFriendIcon">
                                                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nameContainer">


                        <div class="nameInfo">
                            <div class="realName"></div>
                            <div class="primaryInfo">Halo 5: Guardians - Arena: Slayer (Xbox One)</div>
                            <div class="secondaryInfo"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <img alt="Selected" aria_label="Selected" class="selectedBoxIcon" src="https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/social/images/selected_box.png" title="Selected" />
            </li>
            </ul>
</div>
            <ul class="actionButtons">
                <li class="action"></li>
                <li class="cancel"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From this data I would like to create “3” groups.

> Group 1 = Data from: `<div id="pendingRequestsContent"class="pendingRequestsContent"> </div>`
>
> Group 2 = Data from: `<div id="favoritesContent"class="favoritesContent"></div>`
>
> Group 3 = Data from: `<div id="friendsContent" class="friendsContent" role="list"></div>`

**(The way the data is presented in this “3” group is identical.)**

For each group I would like to get “the number” in

```
<div class="title">
                SomeText (the number)
            </div>
```

Each group has a `<div class="gamerList">` which contains each player data.
Each individual players data is contained in `<li … </li>`
Form each `<li … </li>`, I would like to gather the fallowing info;

- `data-gamertag=" this is the desired data "`
- `data-isfavorite="False"` (This is a statement True/False)
- `data-isonline="True"` (This is a statement True/False)
- This specific data (https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=z951ykn43p4FqWbbFvR2Ec.8vbDhj8G2Xe7JngaTToBrrCmIEEXHC9UNrdJ6P7KIFXxmxGDtE9Vkd62rOpb7JehA8dSapBHnH1CYJpGcvrqx3u3aQ5NMCKRX1WaLAVwB&format=png) in the following:

`<img alt="gamertag" aria-label="gamertag" class="gamerpic" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=&#39;https://assets.xbox.com/xweb-1601-29018-rtm-rolling/common/images/default_gamerpic.png&#39;" src="https://images-eds-ssl.xboxlive.com:443/image?url=z951ykn43p4FqWbbFvR2Ec.8vbDhj8G2Xe7JngaTToBrrCmIEEXHC9UNrdJ6P7KIFXxmxGDtE9Vkd62rOpb7JehA8dSapBHnH1CYJpGcvrqx3u3aQ5NMCKRX1WaLAVwB&amp;format=png&amp;h=100&amp;w=100" title="gamertag"></img>`

- `<div class="realName"> this is the desired data </div>`
- `<div class="primaryInfo">this is the desired data</div>`
- `<div class="secondaryInfo"> this is the desired data </div>`

The goal is for each `<li … </li>` in each group, a player will be created named with this data:  `data-gamertag=" this is the name of the player"`. And each player will contain the other data collected.

I would like to have this groups created and saved in a file (was thinking of making it a “.txt” file, but feel free to suggest any other format if you think it would be better), so that the program can read them latter and assign each players value to an object.

It's going to take me some time and a lot of headaches to finish this project, but I would definitely be able to proceed with the complicated parts when I get the answer to this question.

**Please help me out if possible. Anyone that helps in the creation of this tool/software will definitely be thanked and mentioned in it if desired.**

Comment: Google HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Or try [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)

Comment: Well, yes. I know that this can be done using HtmlAgilityPack. I was hoping someone could give me an example of it using the code I provided. That way I can apply the same method to the entire code.